# Python in Power BI - Set background colour for matplotlib box plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, powerbi

I am plotting a box plot using Python in Power BI. I have set the background colour of the Power BI report page to yellow and am trying to set the background colour of the python visual. I have the following code currently.

```
matplotlib.rc('axes', facecolor = 'red')
dataset.boxplot(column='daily_return', by='name', grid=False, figsize=(15,4))
matplotlib.pyplot.title('')
matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle('')
matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel('')
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

The above code results in the following picture...
[image: python output]

As can be seen, there is still some white space. How do I get that to be red, which I will eventually change to my Power BI background colour.

**If I can make the background transparent though, that'd be best**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following worked...

```
matplotlib.rc('savefig', transparent = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.rcParams['figure.facecolor'] = 'Red'
```

It will make the same color for complete fig.

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.rcParams['savefig.facecolor'] = 'grey'
```

Debbuged all parms and seen that Power Bi was displaying the rendered image then the live one.